# ionic - ngxs failed to implement

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngxs

I created a complete new ionic project with `ionic start`.
And then i added ngxs like so `npm install @ngxs/store --save`. But i have an error, when starting the app.

I implemented also the store in `app.module.ts`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestState } from './core/state/test/test.state';
import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([TestState]),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot({ disabled: environment.production }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.7.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.6",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

And this is the error i get:

./node_modules/@ngxs/store/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/ngxs-store.js:2667:6-17 - Error: export 'ɵivyEnabled' (imported as 'ɵivyEnabled') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, App...

Why is this? I don't understand. Is it, because of the new angular version? I don't get it.

Comment: Revert back to 15.2.1 solves the problem on my site

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same here

Comment: İts not related to ionic. It throws this error when I create a new ng project and then adds ngxs dependency. But I have one old project that contains the same package.json dependencies. I deleted the node_modules folder and then I ran the npm install. That project was running correctly. I am giving this error when I create a new ng or ionic not different, adding ngxs dependency, adding to the app.module imports.

Comment: I have also faced this issue When I upgraded my angular project version from 14.2.x to 15.2.1. This issue is solved after I have uninstalled angular/core and angular/cli, then installed that version(15.2.1) again: `npm i @angular/core@15.2.1 @angular/cli@15.2.1`. Solution may be strange but it solves this issue

Answer (score 1):

I found a hint that worked for me. Maybe it will work for you too.
Developers released a new package a few months ago. so for that run this:

> npm install @ngxs/store@3.7.6-dev.master-dcdd391

Reference: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1818#issuecomment-1345649171